# How can you edit Sitecore desktop shortcuts?

Tags: sitecore

Anyone know how to edit the name of the Sitecore desktop shortcuts? I'm using the [Advanced System Reporter](http://trac.sitecore.net/AdvancedSystemReporter) module, and creating a desktop shortcut from there, but now I can't change the name of the item.

I know that you can right click on the Sitecore desktop shortcut and choose properties so change the information of the link....but how can I change the name of the shortcut?

The properties have a field 'Name', that even when I change it, the shortcut doesn't change (even after a desktop refresh).

I tried changing the 'Link' field on the properties as well, but then the link disappeared.

Do these exist in the core database somewhere? Can I get back the one that I just lost (by changing the Link field)?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore do you use? I'm working on Sitecore 6.6 and editing the 'Name' field in the 'Properties' window works for me - the text of the shortcut is changed on the desktop as well.

Comment: And from what I know the shortcut links are stored within user profile (aspnet_profile table in the core database) but in the binary column, so you won't be able to edit it in the database directly.

Comment: I'm using Sitecore 6.5 Update 3. I'm not sure if this issue only exists for all desktop links or just those created through the Advanced System Reporter.

Thanks for the info about the user profile. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through further research, I found that for normal links, the name can be edited by right clicking the link, selecting 'Properties' and changing the 'Name' field.

Unfortunately, Links generated through the Advanced System Reporter don't update on the desktop when this Name property is changed.

It seems that the links for these desktop shortcuts are a combination of items in the core database and values in the User profile in the aspnet_profile DB table (also in core, but only viewable through SQL).
This value is stored in the PropertyValueBinary field, which, as the name suggests, is all in binary, and can't (or shouldn't) be edited.

One way around this is to:-

1. Create the desktop link, which will be called something by default (i.e 'SalesReport').
2. Open up the core database in Sitecore, and navigate to */sitecore/content/Applications/Advanced System Reporter/Links*. Then find the folder for your username.
3. Find the item that was created for the link (in this case it'll be 'SalesReport'), and change the value of the field 'Display name' to whatever you want the link called (i.e 'Sales Report for May'.

**Note:** You may want to change the name of the item as well, so that it won't get lost in other desktop links created in the future and will be easier to find later. In this case you will need to:-

1. Go back to the desktop, right click the shortcut and choose Properties.
2. Manually change the end of the 'Link' field to the name you want to call the item (i.e change it from 'SalesReport' to 'Sales Report for May'.)
3. When you click OK, the shortcut will disappear. This is expected.
4. Open up the core database in Sitecore again, and find the item you're changing. (i.e */sitecore/content/Applications/Advanced System Reporter/Links/SalesReport*
5. Change the name to exactly what you changed it to in step 2.

The link will reappear on the desktop, it'll have the correct name, and will be easy to locate in the Sitecore DB in the future.